# Less number of timer interrupts when some user process is running

Tags: load, kernel, interrupt

In a node we saw that the time is always drifting and ntp jitter is very high.
When we checked the number of interrupts through vmstat in the host and it was around 40-50 interrupts, which should be normally around 1000 + in these machines. When we stopped the java processes and checked the interrupts, it is back to normal around 1K. Also

```
cat /proc/interrupts ;  sleep 2 ; cat /proc/interrupts
```

was showing around 200 interrupts when the java processes were running and around 2k when the processes were stopped.

I think delay of timer interrupts can explain

1. High load on the machines : as the processes are not getting kicked of the processor after the quantum, more number of processes are in run queue and  hence high load
2. Very slow response : Well, the commands we are running might not be getting scheduled again due to no timer interrupts after quantum

But unable to explain

1. Low %cpu usage

So few questions here :

1. What is happening to the interrupts ?
2. Timer interrupts are of highest preference ( irq0 ) and cannot be ignored. So how come ( if at all ) user lever processes can cause this ?

Comment: What kernel version is this? Pretty sure JVMs ran pretty poorly on pre-2.6 kernels because of the high number of threads and the scheduler design. Your testing code here may not be getting scheduled like you think, which would affect the number of interrupts you see in between runs.

Comment: Kernel version is 2.6.18.x. We checked out the number of interrupts by using vmstat (fun part was both interrupts and context switching was reduced). /proc/interrupts too showed a reduced number in timer interrupts when the java code was running.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an hardware issue. Killing the user program correcting the system was coincidental. Also http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/KnownOsIssues#Section_9.2.1.1. talks about a similar kind of issue.